# Overflow: no-content?

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to make a web page, and I set the overflow property of a div element because I thought it would be an easy way to show content if the page is a certain size without using Javascript. It wouldn't work on IE or Firefox, so I looked it up at [the w3schools.com reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp), and it wasn't listed on there either. Why is this in Visual Studio if both IE and Firefox don't support it, and it's not on this reference, and more importantly, is there an actual property that does the same thing? (It says that if the content of the box overflow, then it doesn't show any of the content.)

Comment: Couldn't resist from putting [this](http://w3fools.com/) link.

Comment: Do you mean that if there is overflow, you want to hide all of the content of that container rather than just what is actually overflowing?

Comment: [w3schools is anything but an accurate reference.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @MartyWallace Yes, if something overflows, all of the content is hidden, not just the overflowing content.

Comment: Lol, I didn't know it was a bad resource, W3Schools is where I learned HTML, so I always assumed it was a really good source

Comment: Is this question asking how to achieve what you want, or purely questioning the existence of `overflow: no-content`?

Comment: @MartyWallace both because I thought I was doing something wrong but since it hasn't been implemented in browsers yet I'm not really sure how to do it

Comment: (If it's possible with just CSS, if you HAVE to use scripting, then I can do it but the less scripts I have to use on my site, the better)

Comment: @leaf68, it's probably a good idea to prefer scripting instead of new CSS features, especially if your audience is likely to use the anti-browser whose name must not be spoken (and most audiences are very likely to use it).

Comment: Good point, I forgot I still have to rewrite half of my CSS for older versions of the anti-browser, wouldn't want to add more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `no-content` value for `overflow` was introduced in [this CSS3 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box), but as of early 2013 there are no known implementations. The working draft is quite antiquated, but the new values are still present in the editor's draft, so it might still get implemented to spec someday.

I can't speak for why this already exists in VS2012, nor do I know of any other way to achieve this effect in pure CSS.